# How to follow HTTP redirects inside nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx-based HTTP proxy and I would like to process all HTTP redirects inside it so that clients get only the last response in the redirect chain.

The basic code looks like:

```
location /proxy {
    rewrite ^/proxy/([^/]+) $1 break;

    proxy_pass http://$uri/;
}
```

My attempt at following 1 level redirects is this:

```
error_page 301 302 307 =200 @redir;
```

... and having this named location:

```
location @redir {
    proxy_pass $proxy_location;
}
```

Only there's no $proxy_location variable and I failed to find a way of creating it. It should contain the value of `Location:` header received from upstream.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you want the variable [$upstream_http_location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#variables).

Variables that begin with $proxy* control what goes from nginx to the upstream. The $upstream* series of variables contains information about the response that nginx itself receives. You can get any aribitrary HTTP header received from an upstream server with $upstream_http_headername.

Note that these $upstream variables cannot be anything but null until the response is received from the upstream server, so there are some limitations on their use.

Comment: by the rules of stack overflow you should not provide links, which may change in the future.  instead you should provide precise working example. I don't know why this incomplete answer was selected but it is not helpful by the stackoveflow standard. vlad's answer is much more helpful.

Answer (score 41):

Here is the full example of what worked for me:

```
server {
    ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        # You may need to uncomment the following line if your redirects are relative, e.g. /foo/bar
        #proxy_redirect / /;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirect;
    }

    location @handle_redirect {
        set $saved_redirect_location '$upstream_http_location';
        proxy_pass $saved_redirect_location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you have to save the value of $upstream_http_location in a new variable?

Comment: I don't know the exact reason, but it doesn't work otherwise...

Comment: This is great but only catches a single redirect. Any way to handle multiple redirects?

Comment: @ThiefMaster I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46141557/5958455) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm getting the following error `2020/01/23 09:17:46 [error] 1394#0: *1 invalid URL prefix in "", client: xx.xx.28.3, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /test HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"` using the @handle_redirect block, any idea ?

Comment: In my case the line `resolver 127.0.0.53:53;` was needed because of redirects to external domains.

Comment: I also needed to add the `resolver` and `proxy_ssl_server_name` directives. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while trying to proxy the images from https://picsum.photos website. They return a 302 redirect to a HMAC-signed URL when requesting a particular picture.

My solution is based on the [Vlad's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/792035/995702), however I added some extras (marked as `[1]` and `[2]`) to make it working for me:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dog.localhost.direct;
    location / { 
        # [1] pass the server name
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirect;
        proxy_pass https://picsum.photos/id/237/536/354;
    }
    location @handle_redirect {
        set $saved_redirect_location '$upstream_http_location';
        # [2] specify a resolver
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass $saved_redirect_location;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help somebody.